# How to create a dummy if certain columns match each other (by group id) in a time series df?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, dummy-variable

I have a df containing the fertility history of each woman. There are 18 rows for each woman (i.e. id_mdob) because I'm reconstructing her births from the past 18 years.

What I'm trying to do is to generate a dummy variable for **birth_in_year**, where:

- 1.) If date_year in nchild1-nchild10, then 1
- 2.) If date_year in nchild1-nchild10 AND there are matching years in any of the nchild1-nchild10 columns (i.e. kids born in the same year), then 2

For example, for id_mdob_sy (11323082111985 2011), nchild1 AND nchild2 are 2001, so I want **birth_in_year** to be 2 in the same row as date_year=2001 AND 1 in the same row as date_year=1995 (and the rest to be 0s).

I also want **prev_parity** (i.e. the number of children) to turn to 1 the year the first child is born (in this case, 1995) and turn to 3 when the other 2 kids in 2011 are born (3 because there are a total of 3 kids, 1 born in 1995 and 2 born in 2001).

```
## what I have now (id_mdob_sy: 11323082111985 2011): 
survey_year date_year   prev_parity birth_in_year nchild1 nchild2 nchild3
2011        2011          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2010          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2009          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2008          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2007          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2006          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2005          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2004          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2003          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2002          2              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2001          1              1          2001    2001    1995
2011        2000          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1999          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1998          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1997          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1996          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1995          0              1          2001    2001    1995
2011        1994          0              0          2001    2001    1995
```

```
## desired df
survey_year date_year   prev_parity birth_in_year nchild1 nchild2 nchild3
2011        2011          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2010          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2009          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2008          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2007          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2006          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2005          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2004          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2003          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2002          3              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        2001          1              2          2001    2001    1995
2011        2000          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1999          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1998          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1997          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1996          1              0          2001    2001    1995
2011        1995          0              1          2001    2001    1995
2011        1994          0              0          2001    2001    1995
```

So far I've tried to write code using ifelse, but I can only get birth_in_year to capture the first part (if date_year in nchild1-nchild10==1).
I'm having trouble figuring out how to simultaneously indicate in the same variable (birth_in_year) that if date_year in nchild1-nchild10==1; date_year in nchild1-nchild10 AND matching years in nchild1-nchild10==2. Sorry for the ugly-long code:

```
 test <- pdata_08 %>% 
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(birth_in_year = ifelse(date_year %in% c(nchild1, nchild2, nchild3, nchild4, nchild5, nchild6, nchild7, nchild8, nchild9, nchild10), 1, 0) & (nchild1 == nchild2 & !is.na(nchild1) & !is.na(nchild2)), 2, 0) | (nchild2 == nchild3 & !is.na(nchild2) & !is.na(nchild3)), 2, 0) | (nchild3 == nchild4 & !is.na(nchild3) & !is.na(nchild4)), 2, 0) | (nchild4 == nchild5 & !is.na(nchild4) & !is.na(nchild5)), 2, 0) | (nchild6 == nchild7 & !is.na(nchild6) & !is.na(nchild7)), 2, 0) | (nchild7 == nchild8 & !is.na(nchild7) & !is.na(nchild8)), 2, 0) | (nchild8 == nchild9 & !is.na(nchild8) & !is.na(nchild8)), 2, 0) | (nchild9 == nchild10 & !is.na(nchild9) & !is.na(nchild10)), 2, 0) ) %>%
     group_by(id_mdob) %>%
     mutate(prev_parity = cumsum(birth_in_year))
```

Here are the first 75 rows of the df:

```
structure(list(id_mdob_sy = c("111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", 
"111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", 
"111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", 
"111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", "111990 2018", 
"221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", 
"221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", 
"221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", 
"221995 2018", "221995 2018", "221995 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", 
"311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", 
"311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", 
"311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", "311980 2018", 
"311980 2018", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", 
"321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", 
"321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", 
"321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321988 2015", "321991 2017", 
"321991 2017", "321991 2017"), id_mdob = c(111990, 111990, 111990, 
111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 
111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 221995, 
221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 
221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 
221995, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 
311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 
311980, 311980, 311980, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321991, 321991, 321991
), id = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32), survey_date = structure(c(17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 16467, 
16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 
16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 17167, 
17167, 17167), class = "Date"), survey_year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2017, 2017), date_year = c(2018, 2017, 
2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 
2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 
2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 
2001, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 
2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2015, 2014, 2013, 
2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 
2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 2017, 2016, 2015), prev_parity = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), birth_in_year = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), mom_age = c(28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 
22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 23, 22, 21, 20, 
19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 38, 37, 36, 
35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 26, 
25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 
9, 25, 24, 23), family500_year = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0), prev_parity_1_plus = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0), nchild1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2015, 2015, 
2015), nchild2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    nchild8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), nchild9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), nchild10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), educcat = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2), educcat_college = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), hh_income_net = c(14120, 
    14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 
    14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 5510, 
    5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 
    5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 8203.990234375, 
    8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
    8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
    8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
    8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
    8203.990234375, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 
    4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 
    4800, 3410, 3410, 3410), hh_income_annual_usd = c(45184, 
    45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 
    45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 17632, 
    17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 
    17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 26252.76875, 
    26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
    26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
    26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
    26252.76875, 26252.76875, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 
    15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 
    15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 10912, 10912, 10912), hh_income_annual_log = c(10.7184983208529, 
    10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
    10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
    10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
    10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
    10.7184983208529, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
    9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
    9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
    9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
    9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 10.175526738648, 
    10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
    10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
    10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
    10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
    10.175526738648, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
    9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
    9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
    9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
    9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.29761838008324, 
    9.29761838008324, 9.29761838008324), marital_stat = c(20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10), 
    maritalcat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0), emp_stat = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    3, 3, 3), disability_stat = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), weight = c(1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
    1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1975.36999511719, 
    1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
    1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
    1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
    1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
    1975.36999511719, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 
    1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 
    1368, 1039, 1039, 1039), region = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
    26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 2, 2, 2), birth_country = c(616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), birth_citizenship = c(616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), residence = c(616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
    616, 616, 616, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), rural = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), stock_sq = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), mom_age_sq = c(784, 
    729, 676, 625, 576, 529, 484, 441, 400, 361, 324, 289, 256, 
    225, 196, 169, 144, 121, 529, 484, 441, 400, 361, 324, 289, 
    256, 225, 196, 169, 144, 121, 100, 81, 64, 49, 36, 1444, 
    1369, 1296, 1225, 1156, 1089, 1024, 961, 900, 841, 784, 729, 
    676, 625, 576, 529, 484, 441, 676, 625, 576, 529, 484, 441, 
    400, 361, 324, 289, 256, 225, 196, 169, 144, 121, 100, 81, 
    625, 576, 529), survey_month = c("Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", 
    "Jan 2018", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", 
    "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", 
    "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", 
    "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", "Feb 2015", 
    "Jan 2017", "Jan 2017", "Jan 2017"), month_region = c(12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 
    226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 
    226, 12, 12, 12), month = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "01", "01", "01"
    ), newborn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that your `dput` object's evety `nchild`s are `0`. I used `df` with table above.

```
df <- read.table(text = "survey_year date_year   nchild1 nchild2 nchild3
2011        2011                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2010                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2009                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2008                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2007                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2006                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2005                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2004                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2003                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2002                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2001                  2001    2001    1995
2011        2000                  2001    2001    1995
2011        1999                  2001    2001    1995
2011        1998                  2001    2001    1995
2011        1997                  2001    2001    1995
2011        1996                  2001    2001    1995
2011        1995                  2001    2001    1995
2011        1994                  2001    2001    1995 ", header=T)
```

You may try

```
df %>%
  mutate(birth_in_year = rowSums(date_year == select(., contains("nchild")))) %>%
  arrange(date_year) %>%
  mutate(prev_parity = cumsum(birth_in_year))

   survey_year date_year nchild1 nchild2 nchild3 birth_in_year prev_parity
1         2011      1994    2001    2001    1995             0           0
2         2011      1995    2001    2001    1995             1           1
3         2011      1996    2001    2001    1995             0           1
4         2011      1997    2001    2001    1995             0           1
5         2011      1998    2001    2001    1995             0           1
6         2011      1999    2001    2001    1995             0           1
7         2011      2000    2001    2001    1995             0           1
8         2011      2001    2001    2001    1995             2           3
9         2011      2002    2001    2001    1995             0           3
10        2011      2003    2001    2001    1995             0           3
11        2011      2004    2001    2001    1995             0           3
12        2011      2005    2001    2001    1995             0           3
13        2011      2006    2001    2001    1995             0           3
14        2011      2007    2001    2001    1995             0           3
15        2011      2008    2001    2001    1995             0           3
16        2011      2009    2001    2001    1995             0           3
17        2011      2010    2001    2001    1995             0           3
18        2011      2011    2001    2001    1995             0           3
```